# Do I need an IP whitelist on top of a VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip, openvpn

My company requires me to access resources through a VPN connection -- specifically, an OpenVPN client configured to require a password plus an authenticator token. But the company also restricts access by IP; any new IP address needs to be whitelisted before the VPN connection will work (e.g., if I'm at a coffee shop or something).

Is this level of security justified? Under what circumstances? Against what specific threat vector is the whitelist protecting that the VPN isn't?

Answer (score 3):

Limiting from what IP addresses the VPN is accessible can be a useful part of a defense in depth strategy. This way attackers cannot exploit vulnerabilities in the VPN ([which unfortunately happen](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/hackers-exploit-critical-zyxel-firewall-flaw-in-ongoing-attacks/), [and can result in massive attacks](https://sektorcert.dk/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/SektorCERT-The-attack-against-Danish-critical-infrastructure-TLP-CLEAR.pdf)), cannot use stolen credentials, try brute forcing or other attacks - unless their source IP address is explicitly whitelisted.

Of course, like many security measures this can be inconvenient both for the user and for the administrator. If this added hassle is considered worth the reduced risk depends on what needs to be protected, what the actual threats are and on the risk appetite of the organisation.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the risk here is not that an attacker can steal/break my 2FA credentials or decrypt my traffic (except maybe the NSA), but that they might exploit some zero-day vulnerability in the VPN hardware or protocol itself?

Comment: @Sasgorilla: One of the risk is that the VPN gateway has a vulnerability, and there were several such vulnerabilities in the past even from will established vendors (Pulse VPN, Cisco, Zyxel, Fortinet, ...). But stolen credentials can still be a problem even with 2FA. While 2FA using authenticator is better than no 2FA it still is vulnerable to real-time phishing attacks like described in https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/reelphish-real-time-two-factor-phishing-tool